# How can I run both json_serializable and my custom builder?

Tags: dart, json-serializable, build-runner

`package:my_custom_type_generator`

`build.yaml`

```yaml
builders:
  extractTypes:
    import: "package:my_custom_type_generator/builder.dart"
    builder_factories: ["extractTypes"]
    build_extensions: {'$lib$': ['extracted-types.json']}
    build_to: source
    auto_apply: dependents
```

`package:my_custom_type_annotation`

`annotation.dart`

```dart
@Target({TargetKind.classType})
class MyCustomType extends JsonSerializable {
  const MyCustomType() : super(explicitToJson: true, includeIfNull: false);
}
```

`package:custom_type_project`

`some_cool_object.dart`

```dart
part 'some_cool_object.g.dart';

@MyCustomType()
class SomeCoolObject {
  final String name;
  final int theAgeOfAThing;
  SomeCoolObject({required this.name, required this.theAgeOfAThing});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SomeCoolObjectToJson(this);
  factory SomeCoolObject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SomeCoolObjectFromJson(json);
}
```

My custom builder finds the annotations and outputs the data that I need from them. I would also like for `json_serializable` to process these same annotations, which is why the annotation extends from `JsonSerializable`.

In the project package, I've found that if I don't include `json_serializable` in my `dev_dependencies`, my builder produces the desired output. But if I do include `json_serializable`, then my builder stops producing output, and `json_serializable` produces output instead.

Is there a way I can convince both `json_serializable` and my custom builder to both run? I assume I need to adjust a build.yaml somewhere, but I have no idea where or what needs to be added.